# SQL Server - do returned row values all exist in a set

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, exists

I'm working on a stored procedure where I have a select query that can return multiple values. I'm looking for a way to see if those values exist in a different set of static values declared in the procedure.

So far it looks something like this:

```
DECLARE
  @MachId1 = 1,
  @MachId2 = 2,
  @MachId3 = 3

SELECT DISTINCT pr.Machine from POs as rpo, Records as pr WHERE BoxId = @StoredProcParam and pr.PONO = rpo.poNo

-- I need to see if all the rows returned from the select query exist as a subset of {1, 2, 3}
```

Not entirely sure how to do this yet. I'm looking at using EXISTS but don't know how to define the set {1,2,3}. Maybe as a table, but how will this affect the performance of the stored proc?

SQL Server 2008

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. But you really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Please provide - as text within the question, *not* as picture attachments - sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Must the result set be equal to {1, 2, 3}, i.e. does the query have to return exactly {1, 2, 3} or must the result just be a subset of {1, 2, 3} or equal to it, e.g. {1} is fine, {1, 3} is fine, {1, 2, 3} is fine etc?

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for the response. The result set can be a subset of {1,2,3} or the entire set. So {1,3} is valid, {1,2,3} is valid, and {1,4} would be invalid.

Comment: @SeanLange why? From your link it just seems like it makes the query more clear and less error prone. It doesn't provide any optimization. I should be able to choose my own syntax.

Comment: Sure you can choose to write code that is more error prone and difficult to maintain. That is certainly your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXCEPT` to set minus the values from the result. If that results in an empty set the result must have been a (possible empty) subset of the values. If not, then the remaining element is not a member of the set of values. To check for the empty set you can use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT
                      pr.machine
                      FROM pos rpo
                           INNER JOIN records pr
                                      ON pr.pono = rpo.pono
                      WHERE boxid = @storedprocparam
               EXCEPT
               SELECT machid
                      FROM (SELECT @MachId1 machid
                            UNION
                            SELECT @MachId2 machid
                            UNION
                            SELECT @MachId3 machid) x)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Yes';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No';
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this logic will work. Can't run the query due to syntax in the union sub-queries though. I'll follow up and accept if I can get it working

Comment: Seems to be something with the closing parentheses on the not exists query, not sure why though. It seems valid to me.

Comment: @Lamar: Ah, subquery needs an alias... Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WHERE` IN clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.Machine from POs as rpo, Records as pr WHERE BoxId in (1,2,3) and pr.PONO = rpo.poNo
```

These values can also come from another table.

```
SELECT firstname FROM person where id in (select person_id from company where name = ‘Google’)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to see if the boxId is in the set, but instead trying to see if the result of the select query is in the set. In this case, the pr.Machine value set.